# how to access the struct?

Tags: c

```
struct result {
  int number;
  int length;
};

struct result findLongestSeq(int intarray[], int size) {
  result->number // undefined symbol
}
```

how to access the struct result inside the function findLongestSeq?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct result {
  int number;
  int length;
};

struct result findLongestSeq(int intarray[], int size) {
  struct result result;
  result.number = 0;
  result.length = 42;
  return result;
}
```

If you are dealing with `struct result foo` then you access its members via `foo.number`.
If however you are dealing with a pointer to foo (`struct result *foo`) then you access its members via `foo->number`.

If you were to manually allocate your result struct via

```
struct result *result = (struct result *)malloc(sizeof (struct result));
```

Then you'd have to access its members via `result->number` (and would be responsible for freeing it once not used anymore).

---

Further more I'd rather use this for the sake of better readability:

```
typedef struct {
  int number;
  int length;
} ResultStruct;
```

This way you can then use `ResultStruct result;` instead of redundant and verbose `struct result result;`.

Comment: You probably intended `struct result result;`

Comment: Ouch, sure I did. Thanks! And this is why I tend to typedef my structs. :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that by simply typing

```
struct result {
  int number;
  int length;
};
```

you only define how a struct with name result actually looks like, i.e. of what parts it is made up. This is a general definition, but you have variable of that type yet.

To access values of this struct you have to create a variable by

```
struct result myResult;
```

or however you want to call it. At this point you are able to access the members of this struct with  `myResult.number`